# Java android Cmake problem with executing native build

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with build a project on my PC. On my laptop I don't have such a problem, When I trying to compile a project I have an error and in message I see this:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\ElteGps 022\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\ElteGps 022\Pictures\ipgo\PGOManager_AS2\app -BC:\Users\ElteGps 022\Pictures\ipgo\PGOManager_AS2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\ElteGps 022\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\ElteGps 022\Pictures\ipgo\PGOManager_AS2\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\ElteGps 022\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\ElteGps 022\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-15}
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/ElteGps 022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/ElteGps 022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/ElteGps 022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/Users/ElteGps
  022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"
  is not able to compile a simple test program.
  It fails with the following output:
   Change Dir: C:/Users/ElteGps 022/Pictures/ipgo/PGOManager_AS2/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
  Run Build Command:"C:/Users/ElteGps
  022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/ninja.exe" "cmTC_21eab"
  [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_21eab.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
  FAILED:
  C:\Users\ELTEGP~1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe
  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain="C:/Users/ElteGps
  022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64"
  --sysroot="C:/Users/ElteGps
  022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot" -isystem C:/Users/ElteGps
  022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
  -D__ANDROID_API__=15 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables
  -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a
  -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb
  -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_21eab.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c "C:\Users\ElteGps
  022\Pictures\ipgo\PGOManager_AS2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"
Error:error: no such file or directory:
  '022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi'
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/ElteGps 022/Pictures/ipgo/PGOManager_AS2/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/ElteGps 022/Pictures/ipgo/PGOManager_AS2/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\ElteGps 022\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\ElteGps 022\Pictures\ipgo\PGOManager_AS2\app -BC:\Users\ElteGps 022\Pictures\ipgo\PGOManager_AS2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\ElteGps 022\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\ElteGps 022\Pictures\ipgo\PGOManager_AS2\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\ElteGps 022\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\ElteGps 022\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-15}
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/ElteGps 022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/ElteGps 022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/ElteGps 022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/Users/ElteGps
  022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"
  is not able to compile a simple test program.
  It fails with the following output:
   Change Dir: C:/Users/ElteGps 022/Pictures/ipgo/PGOManager_AS2/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
  Run Build Command:"C:/Users/ElteGps
  022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/ninja.exe" "cmTC_8e4d3"
  [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8e4d3.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
  FAILED:
  C:\Users\ELTEGP~1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe
  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain="C:/Users/ElteGps
  022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64"
  --sysroot="C:/Users/ElteGps
  022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot" -isystem C:/Users/ElteGps
  022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
  -D__ANDROID_API__=15 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables
  -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a
  -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb
  -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_8e4d3.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c "C:\Users\ElteGps
  022\Pictures\ipgo\PGOManager_AS2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"
Error:error: no such file or directory:
  '022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi'
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/ElteGps 022/Pictures/ipgo/PGOManager_AS2/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/ElteGps 022/Pictures/ipgo/PGOManager_AS2/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I can not compile in my PC but in my laptop it 's works correttly I don't have a probleme I have dowload a cmake . I don't have an idea what I have to do wrong

Comment: What types of processors do you have on your PC and your laptop?

Comment: @KarolKulbaka on pc I have a i5 on laptop I have i7

Comment: `Error:error: no such file or directory:
  '022/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi'` <-- There's a pretty good clue. Don't use paths that contain spaces.